# Invalid Jalali year -100721 in dp-date-picker

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using `ng2-jalali-date-picker` in angular 8 and select data from db and show on a table,I need to edit some records and show selected record fields on a form with `db-date-picker` component but in date filed that ‍‍‍map to `db-date-picker` occur `ERROR Error: Invalid Jalali year -100721.`

`<dp-date-picker dir="rtl" [config]="datePickerConfig" mode="daytime" theme="dp-material custome-date" formControlName="time" name="created_at">
  </dp-date-picker>`

`public datePickerConfig = {
    format: 'yyyy/MM/dd'
  }`

The field on table :

`<td class="text-center">
    {{ customerTdf.tdf.created_at | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}
  </td>`

The date that come from db is like‍‍‍‍‍‍ :‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍`1398-11-30T19:36:44+03:25`
‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by converting input value to component 

`let MomentDate = moment(customerTDF.tdf.created_at);
let m = MomentDate.locale('fa').format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');`

and map it to form field 

`this.fallForm.get("time").setValue(m);`